# In R, how to combine two dataframes while there are multiple lists that need to be match?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

**20220418updates**

I change my data frames to be more like the real one

*”NA”and “-3” means missing values*

```
> dfA
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  city  name  bloodtype pulse20 pulse21
  <chr> <chr> <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl>
1 CityA Angel A              78      79
2 CityA Bob   B              90      91
3 CityB Cathy A              60      64
4 CityB Dean  B              70      71
5 CityC Ellen O              60      -3
6 CityC Faye  AB             75      -3
```

```
> dfB
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  city  name  bloodtype pulse21
  <chr> <chr> <chr>       <dbl>
1 CityC Ellen O              65
2 CityC Faye  AB             79
3 CityC Gaven O              68
```

I used join to combine them into df_joined

```
library(dplyr)
df_joined <- 
  dfA %>% 
  full_join(dfB, by = c("city", "name"), suffix = c("", "_repla"))
df_joined
#”repla”stands for “replacement”
```

```
   > df_joined
# A tibble: 7 × 7
  city  name  bloodtype pulse20 pulse21 bloodtype_repla pulse21_repla
  <chr> <chr> <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>                   <dbl>
1 CityA Angel A              78      79 NA                         NA
2 CityA Bob   B              90      91 NA                         NA
3 CityB Cathy A              60      64 NA                         NA
4 CityB Dean  B              70      71 NA                         NA
5 CityC Ellen O              60      -3 O                          65
6 CityC Faye  AB             75      -3 AB                         79
7 CityC Gaven NA             NA      NA O                          68
```

I can mutate them one by one but there are more “.repla” columns for like 100+

So what would be the efficient way to match the similar column names and mutate them, for instance, fill all the new data from “formercolumnnames.repla”
to”formercolumnnames”

I checked the across() help documents but still don’t  quite understand how to connect it into a clear way.
Thank you for your help^^

**20220417former questions**

I have 2 data frames,

1. dfA is a large one including all cities and all health data 2020-2021 except for health data of city c in 2021 which is marked as “-3”.

---

dfA

- City   Name  Pulse20  Pulse21
- CityA  Amy   77         78
- CityB  Bob   80         79
- CityC  Cathy 79         -3

---

2. dfB is a small one including the data I want to fill in dfA

---

dfB

- City   Name  Pulse21
- CityC  Cathy 80

---

**Request：**
1.how to combine this two dataframe in a common use way？

2.if I use “full_join”，the Pulse21 would be listed into “Pulse21.x””Pulse21.y”，therefore I need to do more bind jobs

3.For the record，in my real data，
each city has more than 500 people，
and the health data would be like 100 and more.

4. So is there any other things I can to make it more simple and efficient？ thanks a lot！

Comment: when you say you combine, do you mean changing the -3 to 80?

Comment: Yes, and there are more data, all the  missing data are written as “-3”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this.

Most of them rely on you first changing your `-3` values into `NA` values, e.g. by `mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ifelse(.x == -3, NA_real_, .x)))`.

Under are some examples.

#### `dplyr::rows_upsert`

By far the easiest way of doing this is by turning using `dplyr::rows_upsert()`. This will update your missing rows with non-missing data, and insert rows which don't exist in your first df.

```r
library(dplyr)

dfA %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ifelse(.x == -3, NA_real_, .x))) %>% 
  dplyr::rows_upsert(dfB, by = c("city", "name"))
#> # A tibble: 7 × 5
#>   city  name  bloodtype pulse20 pulse21
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 CityA Angel A              78      79
#> 2 CityA Bob   B              90      91
#> 3 CityB Cathy A              60      64
#> 4 CityB Dean  B              70      71
#> 5 CityC Ellen O              60      65
#> 6 CityC Faye  AB             75      79
#> 7 CityC Gaven O              NA      68
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

> Note that this function is still experimental, and might change with future updates of dplyr.

#### `full_join()` and `pivot_longer()`

If we first join the two dataframes with different suffixes, we can have `tidyr::pivot_longer()` merge them for us. This will first create a long dataframe with combinations between `dfA` and `dfB`, but `na.omit()` ensures that we only keep values where there are none missing values:

```r
library(dplyr)

dfA %>% 
  full_join(dfB, by = c("city", "name"), suffix = c("_A", "_B")) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ifelse(.x == -3, NA_real_, .x))) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    ends_with(c("_A", "_B")), 
    names_to = ".value", 
    names_pattern = "(.*)_.*",
    values_drop_na = TRUE
  ) %>% 
  na.omit()
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#>   city  name  pulse20 bloodtype pulse21
#>   <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1 CityA Angel      78 A              79
#> 2 CityA Bob        90 B              91
#> 3 CityB Cathy      60 A              64
#> 4 CityB Dean       70 B              71
#> 5 CityC Ellen      60 O              65
#> 6 CityC Faye       75 AB             79
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

> Note that this solution removes the rows which only exists in `dfB`.

#### `bind_rows()` and `summarise()`

By first using `bind_rows()` we can combine the two dfs by rows. By grouping on the id columns, we can summarise the data using e.g. `median(na.rm = TRUE)` which will remove missing values for us:

```r
library(dplyr)

dfA %>% 
  bind_rows(dfB) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ifelse(.x == -3, NA_real_, .x))) %>% 
  group_by(city, name, bloodtype) %>% 
  summarise(
    across(
      everything(),
      ~median(.x, na.rm = TRUE)
    )
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'city', 'name'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 7 × 5
#>   city  name  bloodtype pulse20 pulse21
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 CityA Angel A              78      79
#> 2 CityA Bob   B              90      91
#> 3 CityB Cathy A              60      64
#> 4 CityB Dean  B              70      71
#> 5 CityC Ellen O              60      65
#> 6 CityC Faye  AB             75      79
#> 7 CityC Gaven O              NA      68
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

#### Original answer

As in my original answer, you can use `full_join()` and `mutate()` to fix the `NA` and `-3` issue. However, this turns out to be more difficult than the solutions mentioned above when you have many columns.

#### Data

```r
dfA <- tibble::tribble(
  ~city,  ~name,  ~bloodtype, ~pulse20, ~pulse21,
  "CityA", "Angel", "A",              78,      79,
  "CityA", "Bob",   "B",              90,      91,
  "CityB", "Cathy", "A",              60,      64,
  "CityB", "Dean",  "B",              70,      71,
  "CityC", "Ellen", "O",              60,      -3,
  "CityC", "Faye",  "AB",             75,      -3
)

dfB <- tibble::tribble(
  ~city,  ~name,  ~bloodtype, ~pulse21,
  "CityC", "Ellen", "O",              65,
  "CityC", "Faye",  "AB",             79,
  "CityC", "Gaven", "O",              68
)
```

Comment: Thx a lot! That’s inspiring! 
And as given is a simplified data frame, there are more same variable names like“ID”.  I can only join 2 list right？Also， if there are more data, should I mutate them one by one?

Comment: You can only join two dataframes at the time, so if you have more I would do `dfA %>% full_join(dfB) %>% full_join(dfC)` and so on. If you have very many you might want to keep them in a list first, and then reduce the list using `full_join()`.

Comment: If you want to use `mutate()` on multiple columns at the same time you can use `across()`. If you update your example data with something more closely to your actual data, I can update my answer to show you how to do this.

Comment: ohhh that‘s very kind of you！ I'll let you know later

Comment: Hi jpiversen, I updated my question, thanks again

Comment: Answer updated with some possible solutions.

Comment: wow！you are such a genius！though i still need some time to digest the knowledge，so many functions mixed together， thks a lot for your brilliant logic and mind！

Answer (score 0):

```
dplyr::rows_update(dfA, dfB, c('City', 'Name'))

   City  Name Pulse20 Pulse21
1 CityA   Amy      77      78
2 CityB   Bob      80      79
3 CityC Cathy      79      80
```

EDIT:

for your new data, it seems you are updating the original rows while inserting new ones. You could use `row_upsert` ie `update + insert`:

```
dplyr::rows_upsert(dfA, dfB, c('city', 'name'))

# A tibble: 7 x 5
  city  name  bloodtype pulse20 pulse21
* <chr> <chr> <chr>       <int>   <dbl>
1 CityA Angel A              78      79
2 CityA Bob   B              90      91
3 CityB Cathy A              60      64
4 CityB Dean  B              70      71
5 CityC Ellen O              60      65
6 CityC Faye  AB             75      79
7 CityC Gaven O              NA      68
```

Comment: thx a lot！can I know more about row_update，for example what kind of data conditions this would apply to ？thank you！

Comment: Hi KU99, I updated my frames to a more real one, could you plz have a look for me, thx for your time^^

Comment: i tried rows_upsert，feel like fits more

Comment: @kai what do you mean by *feels like fits more*??

Comment: rows_update can be used when there is no new rows , rows_upsert can update the former rows and recognize new rows and insert them, sorry for my poor English.

Comment: And what would you do if there are both new rows and new columns needed to be inserted?

Comment: @kai thats right. Choose the one you want ie `row_update`, `row_insert` or `row_upsert`. If YOU ONLY WANT TO CHANGE NA values, use `row_patch`

Comment: @kai i do not understand what you mean by new columns. You will have to give an example. Check the answer I gave. It includes NA for the columns not given.  The question asked here has been FULLY/completely exhausted. You should consider accepting one of the given answers to close the question and ask a new question.

Comment: understand. thks for the instructions， it‘s my first time using SO so not so sure about the protocol.